# Join domain fails on first attempt. works on Second

Tags: powershell, dns

When I execute this script, it fails the first time, but then works when I re-run it...
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
#DNS
$domain = read-host -Prompt "Will this VM join a Domain"
if ($domain -ne "Y")
{
    Set-DnsClientServerAddress -Interfacealias "Ethernet0" -ServerAddresses @("10.123.456.789","10.789.456.123")
       
} 
  else
  {
    $DomainIp = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Domain Controller IP"  
    Set-DnsClientServerAddress -Interfacealias "Ethernet0" -ServerAddresses @($DomainIp) 
    $domainName = Read-Host -Prompt ""Enter Primary DNS Suffix""
    $domaincreds = get-credential
    Add-Computer -DomainName $domainname -Credential $domaincreds
  }
```

I get this error on the first try, but when i run the same script again,
It joins without issue:

```
Add-Computer : Computer 'MyTestVM' failed to join domain 'MyDC.com' from its current workgroup 'WORKGROUP' 
with following error message: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
At C:\temp\Join_Domain.ps1:26 char:9
+         Add-Computer -DomainName $domainname.forest -Credential $doma ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (MyTestVM:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToJoinDomainFromWorkgroup,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
```

Comment: You say it joins on the second attempt without issue, but the code you provide shows that it failed to join again.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, I see where i pasted it twice.... Believe me. If I run the script again it will work

Comment: domain could not be contacted. looks like a network related error to me. Can you do some timing tests to see if you can replicate a certain amount of time that has to pass after you change the network config of the client?

Comment: @DavidTrevor, Good Idea, I will attempt the code below to see if that resolves it. Thank you for your feed back.

Comment: Running this again I noticed the Line: $domainName = Read-Host -Prompt ""Enter Primary DNS Suffix"", has double quotes. Could this have been the issue the whole time?

Answer (score 0):

You say that the second attempt works, but your code output still indicates that it failed.

However, if Add-Computer works on another attempt, why not try more than once in the script?

Try replacing your Add-Computer line with this code to perform the action up to 5 times:

```
for ($a = 1; $a -le 5; $a++)
{

    $JoinError = $false

    try
    {
        Add-Computer -DomainName $domainname -credential $domaincreds -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch
    {
        $JoinError = $true
        $ErrorMsg = "$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }

    # Break out of the loop if no error was encountered
    if (!$JoinError) { break }

    write-host "$ErrorMsg"
    
    Start-Sleep -s 5

}
```

Comment: I like this... I will test this and get back to you. Thanks you

Comment: Shouldn't the ErrorAction be set to SilentlyContinue instead?